# Инспекционная или инспекторская?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Как правильно: инспекционная лаборатория или инспекторская лаборатория? Хотелось бы понять, почему именно так, а не иначе. Относится ли этот вопрос к лингвистике или просто нужно знать, какой из вариантов вошел в обиход?

Answer (score 1):

**Инспекционная** лаборатория - наименование по функциональному признаку (организованная и оборудованная для проведения *инспекций* или проверок). Этот вариант более распространён. Словообразование "**инспекторская**" (с акцентом на должностное лицо какого-либо регионального уровня, в помощь которому лаборатория организована) тоже возможно, если для этого есть конкретное основание, например, (в абстрактном смысле) это может быть лаборатория, находящаяся *в ведении* главного пожарного *инспектора* по региону и дающая заключения *от его имени* о причинах возгорания и прочем. По понятным причинам это более редкий случай.

Answer (score 1):

**Чаще** используются следующие сочетания: **инспекционная лаборатория** (группа), но: **инспекторская** комиссия, проверка.

**Инспекционная группа** ―  создана для проведения инспекций. **Инспекторская проверка** ― это общее определение категории  проверки (по цели и участникам).

Из словаря: **ИНСПЕКЦИЯ**, -и; ж. 1. =Инспектирование. Произвести и. чего-л. 2. Учреждение, организация, осуществляющие инспектирование чего-л. Торговая и. Санитарная и. <Инспекционный,  **Инспекционные органы**. Инспекционная поездка.  **ИНСПЕКТОРСКИЙ,  к Инспектор и Инспекция.** Инспекторская должность. Инспекторская проверка.

**Примеры**

В столицу приехала **инспекционная группа** Международного бюро выставок. При обнаружении подозрительных судов силы НАТО будут их останавливать и при необходимости на борт может быть отправлена **инспекционная группа**. А тут ещё, как назло, нагрянула в школу **инспекторская комиссия** именно на оставшийся месяц.